# Is it possible to pin items to top with ObjectListView?

Tags: objectlistview

Is there any way with ObjectListView to pin items so they will stay at the top of the list regardless of sort order?

Pretty graphic pins would be great but just to get 2-3 items to stay at the top would be great.

Comment: You could probably implement a custom sorter to achieve that. However, your "Model Objects" would have to "know" that they are pinned. In other words, you would probably need a `bool Pinned` property on the object that you can access while sorting. AFAIK there is no native support for pinning.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Great idea. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer. I would be interested how it worked out. If you come up with something, you could extend my answer or post your own one.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no native support for pinning items like that.

You could probably implement a [custom sorter](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-do-some-fancy-sorting) to achieve that. However, your "Model Objects" would have to "know" that they are pinned. In other words, you would probably need a `bool Pinned` property on the object that you can access while sorting.